# React Native Admob Events

Tags: react-native, admob, expo, expo-ads-admob

[image]
How can I track my ads with this events if the ad loaded, not loaded or user earned reward. I mean where should I use these events on React Native. I am using Expo's Admob but I am open for any solutions.

Comment: Hey, Do you find any solution?

Comment: No, and I stopped working on this project